# Recursive reset file permissions on Windows

Tags: windows, security

There is a big, complex directory structure on a relative big [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) partition. Somebody managed to put very bad security privileges onto it - there are directories with randomly given/denied permissions, etc. I already run into permission bugs multiple times, and I found insecure permission settings multiple times (for example, write permissions for "Everyone", or false owners).

I don't have time to check everything by hand (it is *big*).

But luckily, my wishes are very simple. The most common: read/write/execute on anything for me, and maybe read for Everyone.

Is it possible to somehow

- remove all security data from a directory
- and giving my (simple) wishes to overwrite everything there?

On Unix, I used a `chown -R ...`, `chmod -R ...` command sequence. What is its equivalent on Windows?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

NTFS is a bit more fine-grained than RWX, so for this example, I'm just resetting the [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)s to default. If you have a specific collection of [ACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Access_Control_Entry&redirect=no)s, please add them to your question.  Also, if the drive permissions themselves are mangled, we'd need to fix those as well.

Assuming the tree is rooted at D:\files:

```
REM Make local administrators group owner.
takeown /F D:\files /R /A /D Y

REM Reset ACLs to defaults.
icacls D:\files /reset /T /C /L /Q
```

Comment: I get an error saying that 'Y' cannot be used with option '/D'

Comment: @Manticore You didn't provide your full example command, nor any detail about the environment in which you ran it. I did just copy/paste the `takeown` line from my answer and it still works, nearly four years later, on Windows 10 1709.

Comment: @jscott I am just saying what happened to me. Windows 10 1709, too.I copy-pasted it (carefully), ran the command and got back the message. I managed to solve my problem with takeown though. Just had to use different options.

Comment: @Manticore The '/D' option needs a localized input, so for a german Windows install use `takeown /F D:\files /R /A /D J` (J instead of Y) instead.

Comment: @Manticore I got your issue too, this is explained in the help output (`/?`).